# Removing strings character with given input

Tags: python

I need to remove a certain string with the given input. For example,

```
user_input = input("Input File name: ")
```

and the user key in "patient_zero[20150203].txt" and it would like to clean up the file name by removing all instances of square brackets and the contents contained within it.

Output should be "patient_zero.txt". Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expression to remove all square brackets and their contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324466/python-regular-expression-to-remove-all-square-brackets-and-their-contents)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Maybe not, if the OP only wants to target square brackets occurring within the filename itself (but not elsewhere in the input).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the square bracket portion of the filename, you could use:

```py
inp = "patient_zero[20150203].txt"
output = re.sub(r'^(\S+)\[.*?\]\.(\S+)$', r'\1.\2', inp)
print(output)  # patient_zero.txt
```

Comment: may I know what method is this?

Comment: @NgLengPoh I'm using a regular expression replacement with `re.sub`.  Regex is suitable for what you are trying to achieve.  We could also do it more simply by removing all square brackets everywhere, but it might not be what you want.

Comment: I tried and it says that "re" is not defined.

Comment: You must import the module at the beginning of your code: `import re`

Answer (score 0):

using `spplit`

```
var = "patient_zero[20150203].txt"
print(var.split("[")[0] + var.split("]")[1]) # PatientName + FileFormat
```

Comment: it works but may I know how does it work?

Comment: @NgLengPoh This is fundamental String operation. ```split```. Taking out everything before [ and concatenating everything after ] (in case different fie format other than .txt)

Comment: what does [0] and [1] mean?

Comment: indexes, start exploring the split concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "patient_zero[20150203].txt"

print (re.sub(r'\[[\w\s]+\]','',s))
```

Output:

```
patient_zero.txt
```